# Ajax responseText issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Is it possible to get an ajax responseText without the response deleting the previous content?

For example:

```
 <div id="content">

<p>Default content</p>

 </div>
```

After running a normal ajax request with a responseText targeting id="content" the document's previous content changes to:

```
  <div id="content">
  <p>ajax response</p>
</div>
```

Is it possible to keep both "Default content" and "ajax response" in the same div id after the ajax request?

Comment: Problem solved, I just added the previous content to the response text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#content" ).append(myResponseText_Variable);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just `append()` the new ajax content, rather than overwriting with `html()`/`text()`

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to know what you're doing without seeing your code but at a guess you're using `.html()` to display the results. Try using `.append()` instead.